# How to connect to Azure App Configuration from inside a Virtual Machine?

Tags: java, azure-app-configuration

I have a virtual machine through which I need to run a Java application. The config details for the application are stored in the Azure App Configuration.

I created a Service Principal with **App Configuration Data Reader** role. I am using the following code to connect to the App Configuration :

```
TokenCredential ServicePrincipal = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder().authorityHost("https://login.microsoftonline.com")
                .tenantId(System.getenv("AZURE_TENANT_ID"))
                .clientId(System.getenv("AZURE_CLIENT_ID"))
                .clientSecret(System.getenv("AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET"))
                .build();
            
appConfigEndpoint = System.getenv("APP_CONFIGURATION_CONNECTION_STRING");

//Using Service Principal to connect to the APP Configuration Store
configurationClient = new ConfigurationClientBuilder().credential(ServicePrincipal).endpoint(appConfigEndpoint).buildClient();

String config1 = configurationClient.getConfigurationSetting("config1", environment).getValue();
```

But the process seems to be stuck. It creates the **configuration client** but it is not able to retrieve the config value.
Since I am running it from inside the VM, do I need to do something different?
The VM is a linux server and I am trying to call the class file using
`java com.package.ConfigTest`

Comment: Can you provide the error you get? Also `connection-string` != `endpoint`. Your endpoint it part of the connection string, but a different value. Also, you may just want to use an environment credential as that is what you are manually building, or just the default credential should work. https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/main/sdk/identity/azure-identity#credential-classes

Comment: Yeah, the environment variable name is misleading but I am using the endpoint only. But, I have figured out the issue and it is working for me now. I needed to grant my Service Principal permission to the key vault also.